# Reference book for functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

How does Rudin's Functional analysis compare with Reed and Simon's functional analysis. I am a beginner looking for a rigorous and broad text(for self study) and have narrowed it down to these two books. Can I get some insight into the advantages and disadvantages of these two books when compared with each other.

Comment: I am a big fan of Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, but personally wouldn't recommend using Rudin's Functional Analysis as your main text, since he starts from TVS, which is too abstract. I would recommend a book that starts with Hilbert spaces and builds up from there.

Comment: If you are also interested in differential equations you could take a look at 'Functional analysisis, Sobolev Space and partial differential equations' by H. Brezis.

Comment: for an introductory textbook take a look at the book of Ovchinnikov. For a deeper lecture I would choose the book of Brezis.

Comment: Rudin wants to show you how clever he is. Reed and Simon try expose you to standard techniques and advanced material.

Comment: I chose Rudin's. For example, look at Chapter V of Reed-Simons and Chapter 1 of Rudin. While Reed-Simons tell you that every locally convex space is Hausdorff without proof (and not even a hint), Rudin tells you every TVS is Hausdorff with (almost) a proof! Although, admittedly, these books kind of have different foci (Reed-Simon is much more operator-theory oriented), and you need to fill in small details in almost every proof of Rudin's, I still recommend Rudin. Choosing a book by just one comparison doesn't make sense, but there are some more I can list.